# Ruby: Want a Set-like object which preserves order

Tags: ruby, arrays, set

... or alternatively an Array which prevents duplicate entries.

Is there some kind of object in Ruby which:

- responds to [], []= and <<
- silently drops duplicate entries

  is Enumerable (or at least supports find_all)

  preserves the order in which entries were inserted

?

As far as I can tell, an Array supports points 1, 3 and 4; while a Set supports 1, 2 and 3 (but not 4). And a SortedSet won't do, because my entries don't implement <=>.

Comment: You could implement <=> in your entry class.  Perhaps so that when adding an object to the container, it stores an incrementing value into an index in the entry class.

Comment: Or, you could use a Hash, and have the incrementing value put in as the value, with your object as the key.  It may be slower getting the list back (accessing via keys is slow, but possible).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't one as far as I know, and Set by its mathematical nature is meant to be unordered (or at least, implementationally, meant not to guarantee order - in fact its usually implemented as a hash table so it does mess up order).

However, it's not hard to either extend array directly or subclass it to do this. I just tried it out and this works:

```
class UniqueArray < Array
  def initialize(*args)
    if args.size == 1 and args[0].is_a? Array then
      super(args[0].uniq)
    else
      super(*args)
    end
  end

  def insert(i, v)
    super(i, v) unless include?(v)
  end

  def <<(v)
    super(v) unless include?(v)
  end

  def []=(*args)
    # note: could just call super(*args) then uniq!, but this is faster

    # there are three different versions of this call:
    # 1. start, length, value
    # 2. index, value
    # 3. range, value
    # We just need to get the value
    v = case args.size
      when 3 then args[2]
      when 2 then args[1]
      else nil
    end

    super(*args) if v.nil? or not include?(v)
  end
end
```

Seems to cover all the bases. I used OReilly's handy Ruby Cookbook as a reference - they have a recipe for "Making sure a sorted array stays sorted" which is similar.

Comment: Insert doesn't handle variable arguments like the Array version does, and your []= will allow duplicates when using a Range or the start, length version and assigning multiple values (e.g. arr[3..4] = [a, b] or arr[3,2] = [a, b]).  Frankly, I'm not sure how Chris would intend either one of those to work (does a duplicate negate the whole assignment/insertion, or just that particular element?), but it's fine so long as he avoids those cases.

Comment: Also, as a general rule I'd probably delegate to Array instead of extending, but to each his own.

Comment: As it happens, I don't need full Array functionality, so just << will do (and that looks pretty safe). 

Hadn't come across Delegation before, so just looked it up - you learn something new every day.

Comment: Pesto: good point about the range input, I should have just gone with the simpler but slower:
def []=(*args)
  super(*args)
  uniq!
end

Also, delegate to Array? Too formal. I thought I was already showing some restraint by extending instead of just opening array like

class Array; def ...; end ; end

that would actually be considered many to be the most 'rubyful' way to do it - but it still gives me the heebee geebees

Comment: Another inheritance issue here is all of the *other* Array methods. Eg if you add two UniqueArrays then you will get a (surprise!) Plain Old Array back. You could `undef_method` but Array contains a lot of instance methods, a potential maintenance burden. I'd prefer a smaller interface where all methods work as advertised (with Enumerable and Comparable mixed in) rather than a larger inherited interface that might bite me in the future.

Comment: @Rhubarb: the issue Martin mentions is why you'd want to use delegation. It's not a mere stylistic issue. Another issue is performance - if the array becomes large then calling `include?` becomes expensive.

Comment: In general, do not sublcass Array, it's implemented in C and has internal shortcuts to speed up initialisation that mean an initialize with super may not be called. Also things like the + operator will return arrays, not your subclass. Delegate to array, there's a simple library module that makes this really easy, and preserves types for you.

Answer (score 13):

As of Ruby 1.9, the built-in `Hash` object preserves insertion order. For example:

```
h = {}
h[:z] = 1
h[:b] = 2
h[:a] = 3
h[:x] = 0
p h.keys     #=> [:z, :b, :a, :x]

h.delete :b
p h.keys     #=> [:z, :a, :x]

h[:b] = 1
p h.keys     #=> [:z, :a, :x, :b]
```

So, you can set any value (like a simple `true`) for any key and you now have an ordered set. You can test for a key using either `h.key?(obj)` or, if you always set each key to have a truthy value, just `h[obj]`. To remove a key, use `h.delete(obj)`. To convert the ordered set to an array, use `h.keys`.

Because the [Ruby 1.9 `Set` library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/set/rdoc/index.html) happens to be built upon a Hash currently, you can currently use `Set` as an ordered set. (For example, the `to_a` method's implementation is just `@hash.keys`.) Note, however, that **this behavior is not guaranteed** by that library, and *might* change in the future.

```
require 'set'
s = Set[ :f, :o, :o, :b, :a, :r ]  #=> #<Set: {:f, :o, :b, :a, :r}>
s << :z                            #=> #<Set: {:f, :o, :b, :a, :r, :z}>
s.delete :o                        #=> #<Set: {:f, :b, :a, :r, :z}>
s << :o                            #=> #<Set: {:f, :b, :a, :r, :z, :o}>
s << :o                            #=> #<Set: {:f, :b, :a, :r, :z, :o}>
s << :f                            #=> #<Set: {:f, :b, :a, :r, :z, :o}>
s.to_a                             #=> [:f, :b, :a, :r, :z, :o]
```

Answer (score 6):

I like this solution although it requires active_support's OrderedHash

```
require 'active_support/ordered_hash'

class OrderedSet < Set

  def initialize enum = nil, &block
    @hash = ActiveSupport::OrderedHash.new
    super
  end

end
```

=)

Comment: Nice idea. No need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: don't you want to pass the arguments to `initialize` on when you send `super`?

Comment: @hdgarrood When you call `super` without parentheses it automatically passes all parameters from the current method. It's weird-and different from `super()`-but convenient.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a Hash to store the values, and have an incrementing value stored in the value of each Hash pair.  Then you can access the set in a sorted manner, albeit slowly, by accessing the objects via their values.

I'll try to add some code in here later to explain further.

I am aware accessing via values is much slower than by keys.

Update 1: In Ruby 1.9, Hash elements are iterated in their insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I know of, but it wouldn't be hard to roll your own.  Just subclass Array and use a Set to maintain your uniqueness constraint.

One question about silent dropping.  How would this affect #[]=?  If I was trying to overwrite an existing entry with something which was already stored elsewhere, should it remove the would-be-removed element anyway?  I think either way could provide nasty surprises down the road.