# Does Ruby uniq preserve ordering?

Tags: ruby

The documentation doesn't say anything about that (http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq).

Also, is it using a naive O(n^2) search or something else like a hashmap ? In the latter case, should I understand that my elements must have a proper implementation of `hash` and `eql?` when I want to unicize them ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Given the code (in C) for the [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.2/Array.html#method-i-uniq)

```c
rb_ary_uniq(VALUE ary)
{
    VALUE hash, uniq, v;
    long i;

    if (RARRAY_LEN(ary) <= 1)
        return rb_ary_dup(ary);
    if (rb_block_given_p()) {
        hash = ary_make_hash_by(ary);
        uniq = ary_new(rb_obj_class(ary), RHASH_SIZE(hash));
        st_foreach(RHASH_TBL(hash), push_value, uniq);
    }
    else {
        hash = ary_make_hash(ary);
        uniq = ary_new(rb_obj_class(ary), RHASH_SIZE(hash));
        for (i=0; i<RARRAY_LEN(ary); i++) {
            st_data_t vv = (st_data_t)(v = rb_ary_elt(ary, i));
            if (st_delete(RHASH_TBL(hash), &vv, 0)) {
                rb_ary_push(uniq, v);
            }
        }
    }
    ary_recycle_hash(hash);

    return uniq;
}
```

In the general case (the `else` block), it creates a hash from the array (that unifies the key without keeping the order). Then it create a new empty array with the right size. Finally it go through the first Array and when it finds the key in the hash it delete that key and push it to the empty array.

Hence the order is kept.

I'd say the complexity is `O(complexity(ary_make_hash) + N)` in time, which is probably `O(N)`

---

> should I understand that my elements must have a proper implementation of `hash` and `eql?` when I want to unicize them ?

Yes exactly, they should implement both `hash` and `eql?` methods, which almost all `Object`s do.

We can see that if we were to call `uniq` on an array of `BasicObject`s, which do not define the `hash` method, we would get an error:

```
irb(main):023:0> [BasicObject.new, BasicObject.new].uniq
Traceback (most recent call last):
        5: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
        #...
NoMethodError (undefined method `hash' for #<BasicObject:0x000000014311a1e0>)
```

Comment: This is great for I have a need for the preservation of the order the first instance of each unique occurrence is encuntered.ie: { 1,2,1,4,5,4,6,4 } => { 1,2,4,5,6 }

As this "feature" is not documented will it remain the same ?

Comment: Hash insertion order is preserved since ruby 1.9 and upward. Set is built upon an hash. So this will remain the same (see this SO question for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773403/ruby-want-a-set-like-object-which-preserves-order#answer-14468621)